# jekyll _posts is public, can the `published:false` in frontmatter hide my post?

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm new of jekyll, I put jekyll_site folder in my public github_page repository.

When I write blog in /_posts dir and set `published: false` in frontmatter, the web does not show my blog.

**However**, the repository is public, **people can still access the `_post` dir**. In my knowledge, github_page repository has to be `public`. How to private some of my jekyll blog page?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hey, can you share a link to your page (code) or post here your `_config.yml`? HINT: The _post folder should NOT be below the generated _site outut, just the "rendered" versions.  You can not HIDE static content, the urls are there and you can use the url. There is no login or similiar stuff. The whole _site folder will be visible.

Comment: Thank your @KargWare ! Not publishing private content is way I can choose.